# Intermitent error in API Gateway import time

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway

we are trying to create an API Gateway from the import button in the AWS console.

The user policy is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "apigateway:GET"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "apigateway:PUT"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/restapis/`our-api-id`/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As we import the swagger file from the console, it prompts the following error randomly:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::`account-id`:user/`user-id` is not authorized to perform: apigateway:PUT on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1::/restapis/`our-api-id`
```

We don't know why sometimes the same actions works and sometimes does not.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions errors should not be intermittent. However the resource for the PUT action (specifically for put-rest-api operation) should be

```
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "apigateway:PUT"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/restapis/`our-api-id`"
            ]
        }
```